# How to run lxc inside of a chroot

Tags: debian, ubuntu, chroot, cgroups

I'm trying to run lxc inside of a chroot.

```
$ lxc-start -n instrument --logfile=/dev/stdout
lxc-start 20190619141851.659 ERROR    lxc_cgfs - cgroups/cgfs.c:cgfs_init:2359 - cgroupfs failed to detect cgroup metadata
```

I tried to mount (where target the path to my chroot is):

```
/bin/bash -c "sudo mount --bind /proc ${target}/root/proc/"
/bin/bash -c "sudo mount --bind /sys ${target}/root/sys/"
/bin/bash -c "sudo mount --bind /dev ${target}/root/dev/"
/bin/bash -c "sudo mount --bind /dev/pts ${target}/root/dev/pts"

/bin/bash -c "sudo mount --bind /sys/fs ${target}/root/sys/fs"
```

Comment: Since you are bind mounting `/dev`, and `/sys`, the last two commands to bind `/dev/pts`, and `/sys/fs` are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing cgroupfs-mount and running it seems to be enough to 
mount all needed cgroupfs mounts.

```
apt install cgroupfs-mount
/usr/bin/cgroupfs-mount
```